# jQuery UI Tabs content via ajax position() works only in the first tab

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs, positioning

I am new to jQuery/jQuery UI. I am trying to create multiple tabs in a page(sample.html) which loads dynamic content(temp.html) via ajax. Desired effect is content in temp.html should change according to tab selected. I am using [position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) to place some widgets in positions relative to each other.

The problem I am facing is when i click the first tab, everything is working fine. When i click on the second tab positioning does not work. I have added my code below.

**Sample.html**

```
$(function() {
   $("#tabs").tabs({
    ajaxOptions : {
      error : function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
           $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab.");
        },
        cache : false
        }
    });
});

<div id="content" class="content">
   <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="temp.html">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="temp.html">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

**temp.html**

```
#widget1 {
 width: 150px;
 height: 70px;
 top: 20px;
 left: 50px
}

#widget2 {
 width: 150px;
 height: 70px;
}

function resetPositions() {
   $("#widget2").position({
    my : "left top",
    at : "right bottom",
    of : "#widget1",
    offset : "0 50"
    });
   }
$(function() {
  $(".customAccordion").draggable();
  $(".customAccordion").accordion({
    collapsible : true,
    fillSpace : false,
    icons : {
     header : "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
     headerSelected : "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
    }
 });
 resetPositions();
});

<div id="widget1" class="customAccordion">
  <h3><a href="#">Widget 1</a></h3>
  <div>Widget 1</div>   
</div>
<div id="widget2" class="customAccordion">
 <h3><a href="#">Widget 2</a></h3>
 <div>Widget 2</div>
</div>
```

Please do let me know if i am making any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a tricky part of jQuery UI, you need to make sure you **initialize your accordion(s) *BEFORE* your tabs**

```
$(".customAccordion").accordion();
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

- Try first to remove your accordion, see if it helps.
- Then try to initialize your tabs at the very end.

Then you need to verify loading your html page with AJAX will run its included Javascript... If not, you need to **paste that initialization code into the *select* event** of your tabs.

```
$("#tabs").tabs(
{
    select: function(event,ui)
    {
        // initAccordions();
    }
});
```

Comment: I am having tabs and accordions in two different htmls. Only when i select a tab, the page with the accordions is loaded through ajax. So i dont think it is possible to init accordions first?

Comment: I removed the accordions, draggable for the divs. Even after that, positioning was wrong. I debugged the jquery code in firebug and observed this. For the first tab, Widget1's offset() returns a number > 0. But when i click the second tab, Widget1's offset returns 0.

Comment: mhh ok, could you try to add resetPositions(); in a select event like I did in the last part of my answer? Your issue could be related to the $(document).ready() event, or your $(function(), not being reliable in dynamically loaded page.